# How to access NbEditorDocument of a newly opened file in NetBeans IDE?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I want to register for notifications of files being opened and access their [`NbEditorDocument`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-editor/org/netbeans/modules/editor/NbEditorDocument.html) instances. Possibly it's something similar to [this](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqListenForOpenEvents), where `FileObject` instances are accessed instead.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @hjavaher. I can register for `PropertyChangeEvent`s on the `EditorRegistry` and then be notified when an `NbEditorDocument` receives focus. But then I think I have to keep track of what is in the `EditorRegistry` so to make sure it's its new entry. Don't know if there's a more straightforward alternative.

Comment: I suggest you add that information to the Question so you don't get downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen for `EditorRegistry.FOCUS_GAINED_PROPERTY` and keep own track of `EditorRegistry.lastFocusedComponent()` to know when it's a new one.